# Angular Material Accordions not closed on first rendering

Tags: angular, angular-material

I dynamically add Accordions to a tab page. The Panels should all be closed from start. But for a short moment the panels are expanded. Especially you can see that in Firefox. What else can I do, that my panels are closed also on first rendering?

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list|keyvalue:keepOriginalOrder">
     <div *ngIf="item.value.typ==='accordion'">
              <mat-accordion>
                <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]='false'>
                  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                      title
                    </mat-panel-title>
                  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  <div>
                      content
                  </div>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
              </mat-accordion>
    </div>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: That behaviour is quite strange since the expansion panels are closed by default and you actually specify that. Maybe try to lazy load their content to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution. Bug described here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11765

I added to my styles.scss

```
mat-accordion mat-expansion-panel {
  mat-expansion-panel-header {
    height: 40px; // height may be different for you
  }
  .mat-expansion-panel-content {
    height: 0;
  }
  &.mat-expanded {
    mat-expansion-panel-header {
      height: 64px; // height may be different for you
    }
    .mat-expansion-panel-content {
      height: auto;
    }
  }
}
```